# I am trying to make an object randomly spawn into my game for a period of time and when my character walks over the object it despawns

Tags: python, object, random

I cant figure out how to randomly spawn in objects and make them wait despawn after a period of time, or when my sprite touches the object it despawns.

I tried adding in a import random but not sure what to do next

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('newbg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

x = 50
y = 440
width = 40
height = 60
velocity = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

Jump = False
jumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0

randomPos = 0
waitTime = 0


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    global randomPos

    randomPos = random.randint(0,900)

    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x, y))
        walkCount = 0

    pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(randomPos, 480), 10)

    pygame.display.update()


run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > velocity:
        x -= velocity
        left = True
        right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 900 - velocity - width:
        x += velocity
        left = False
        right = True

    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        walkCount = 0

    if not (Jump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            Jump = True
            left = False
            right = False
            walkCount = 0
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            Jump = False

    waitTime =

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

This is the lines of code I have added into my code to try make it

The circle object just blinks randomly across my screen spawns and despawns, not sure what to do

Comment: do you have a class for your objects?

Comment: You can use the sprite class to add object to a group and test if it collides with the player. Or just use colliderect. You can count every frame and have it despawn at a certain number. Do you have more code to post so I can help you more?

Comment: Also make sure you are drawing the circle every frame in the main loop. And make sure you aren't drawing a background over the circle after it is drawn.

Comment: @user2379875 i posted the full code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify you are concerned with the circle spawning and despawing each frame? The reason this is happening is because each frame you draw the circle at a different location:

```
randomPos = random.randint(0,900) 
...
pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(randomPos, 480), 10)
```

So it's only ever at a certain position for a single frame. You need to create an object with a position that remains the same until some elapsed time has passed.
Or you can save the random value and not update it until some condition is met:

```
#Example:

if ready_to_change_location: #Becomes True when some condition is met...
    location = random.randint(0,900)
    ready_to_change_location = False

pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(location, 480), 10)
```